# How to exclude files in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline when building .net core web application

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am completely new to Azure DevOps and YAML.

I am using Azure DevOps with Octopus for CI and CD. And would like to exclude some files generated eg: map files, stats.json, deps.json, etc.,

Can anyone help me how to do this in the azure pipeline yaml to exclude files. Or point me to any kind of documents to look into this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> And would like to exclude some files generated eg: map files,
> stats.json, deps.json, etc.

Are these files generated after the build? If so, you can add this script to your project file:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToExclude Include="$(OutputPath)\stats.json" />
        <FilesToExclude Include="$(OutputPath)\deps.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target AfterTargets="build" Name="Exclude-Files">
        <Delete Files="@(FilesToExclude)"/>
    </Target>
```

It will automatically delete the files you want to execlue after every sucessful build.

Comment: where in my YAML can i add these snippets?